# Azure Functions runtime 2.0 - Cosmos DB Trigger - Dynamic Database & Collection names

Tags: azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

Is it possible to pass the *databaseName* & *collectionName* parameters via a variable or a configurable item to the **CosmosDBTrigger**?

```
 public static void Run([CosmosDBTrigger(
            databaseName: "dbname",
            collectionName: "colname",
            ConnectionStringSetting = "CosmosDbConnectionString",
            LeaseCollectionName = "changefeed-leases")]
             IReadOnlyList<Document> changeFeedDocuments,
           TraceWriter log)
```

Thanks,
Praveen

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can declare them like this:

```
public static void Run([CosmosDBTrigger(
    databaseName: "%dbname%",
    collectionName: "%colname%",
```

And then define two Application Settings called `dbname` and `colname` with the actual names of database and collection.

This is common for all trigger types: see [Binding expressions - app settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-triggers-bindings#binding-expressions---app-settings).